# FreshChat SDK integration -> UncaughtException: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError

Tags: android, uncaught-exception

```
// On button click i am tring to open Freshchat -> Conversation screen
Freshchat.showConversations(getApplicationContext());
```

```
E/UncaughtException: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class 'com.freshchat.consumer.sdk.activity.ChannelListActivity' does not implement interface 'androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner' in call to 'androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner.getLifecycle()' (declaration of 'androidx.lifecycle.LiveData' appears in /data/app/com.healthpole.dentists.debug-X-W_P0gIA-gphdr95wNXzg==/base.apk)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.observe(LiveData.java:172)
        at androidx.loader.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderInfo.setCallback(LoaderManagerImpl.java:100)
        at androidx.loader.app.LoaderManagerImpl.createAndInstallLoader(LoaderManagerImpl.java:400)
        at androidx.loader.app.LoaderManagerImpl.restartLoader(LoaderManagerImpl.java:447)
        at com.freshchat.consumer.sdk.activity.ChannelListActivity.F(Unknown Source:46)
        at com.freshchat.consumer.sdk.activity.ChannelListActivity.onResume(Unknown Source:80)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1412)
        at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:7292)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3776)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3816)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute(ResumeActivityItem.java:51)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:145)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:70)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

```
Project Configuration
minimumSdkVersion -> 21
compileSdkVersion -> 28
FreshChat SDK version -> com.github.freshdesk:freshchat-android:2.6.0
and migrated to androidX
```

`NOTE` As this lib is not migrated to [androidX](https://github.com/freshdesk/freshchat-android/issues/49) so 
I have tried using the updated version of [constraintlayout](https://github.com/freshdesk/freshchat-android/issues/23)
also used [appcompat-v7-28.0.0 and support-v4-28.0.0](https://github.com/techaffinity/freshchat-phonegap/issues/25) lib still facing the same issue.

so my question is what more dependencies I have to changes or add? what is a workaround with this issue?

Comment: i am getting same error

min and max sdk
 minSdkVersion = 21
    targetSdkVersion = 28
    compileSdkVersion = 28
    buildToolsVersion = '26.0.2'

// freshchat version
freshChatVersion = '2.6.1'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have asked the question to FreshChat team they have told us to update the dependency of `appcompact` lib and if still not solved then update other core AndroidX libraries.

So I have updated the `appcompact` lib to `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-beta01` and it is working fine now